# Cordova intercept URL loading of inappbrowser

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I would like to know how to intercept URL loading from inside the WebView in Cordova InAppBrowser.

Currently, I can intercept URL loading from the main WebView with the following code in my `MainActivity`:

```
   final WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.appView.getView();
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new SystemWebViewClient((SystemWebViewEngine) this.appView.getEngine()) {

      @Override
      public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        // Some custom logic
      }
```

But when I load some URL inside InAppBrowser Webview, this code does not intercept that request. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to modify the inAppBrowser code

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/src/android/InAppBrowser.java

On line 646 the webViewClient is set:

```
inAppWebView.setWebViewClient(client);
```

client has the `InAppBrowserClient` class, it's defined on line 742.
You can add the `shouldInterceptRequest` logic there or use your own `WebViewClient` subclass

Comment: Yes. I overrode `onResourceLoad` of `InAppBrowserClient` and now I can intercept requests. Using cordova 5.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the InAppBrowser's executeScript functionality to execute some script inside the IAB once it has loaded the page, then have that script do whatever logic you want, [example from the docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser):

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    ref.executeScript({file: "myscript.js"});
});

Whether or not this would work for you may depend on what your custom logic needs to do, but it may be a path worth investigating.  You could perhaps add event listeners to all the links in the page and run custom logic when they are clicked.